# Модальное окно jquery

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, вёрстка, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Пишу на asp.net mvc, создал модальное окно.

Окно работает, но вот есть проблема, при перезагрузке страницы на сотые секунды постоянно отображаются все теги и текст  который внутри контейнера модального окна (в том месте где и находится контейнер).

Почему так происходит? Именно в asp, тестил в обычной html странице, там все нормально как и здесь

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#modal-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 600,
            show: {
                duration: 1000
            },

            hide: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
            $("#modal-dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
<button id="modal-opener">ok</button>

<div id="modal-dialog" title="Введите данные и мы с вами свяжемся">
        <p>sdsdfsdfsfsfsdf</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер успевает отрисовать html перед тем, как выполнится

`$("#modal-dialog").dialog({ ...`

Сделайте диалог изначально невидимым:

```
<div id="modal-dialog" style="display:none;" ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. А от чего это зависит? Почему только при компиляции в asp такая штука?

Comment: Почему здесь или в обычной html странице не успевает, а там успевает?

Comment: да это от чего угодно зависит - например, от распределения скриптов, css-а и html в странице и логики конкретного браузера

Comment: тут немного не так - в обычной странице, наоборот, успевает загрузить, распарсить и выполнить js, до того как отрендерит html

Comment: Похоже все стало понятно